# Hibernate support for Jakarta Persistence(JPA) 3.0

Tags: hibernate, jpa

JPA 3.0 was released in November 2020 and I guess most JPA providers (Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA) still support JPA 2.2.
Are there any plans to migrate to new version?
It will be not so trivial, because, for example, top-level package has changed (javax.persistence -> jakarta.persistence).

Answer (score 5):

The issue tracker number for it is [HHH-13946](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13946). They've set the target for version 5.5, which I kind of disagree with, because it breaks backwards compatibility, so it should be version 6.0. As for a specific timeline on it, there's never any certainty on that.

Update: The task was rejected and not made it into 5.x.

Comment: Dear @coladict I don't see any version 5.5. Do you have any link to access it? What should the provider element in persistence.xml be?

Comment: 5.5 is planned version, not released.

Answer (score 5):

EclipseLink 3.0 arrived Dec 8th, 2020 implementing [Jakarta Persistence 3.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/). Updated April 7, 2021 to [EclipseLink 3.0.1.](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#download)